# how to add values to csv file using TCL and add space if the number of characters in a value is less than 8

Tags: string, tcl

I am looking for a TCL command to write data into a csv file, at the same time of adding data , I need to add the spaces if the number of characters in each value is less than 8

Below are the sample list of variables I need to add in a line of csv file using TCL command

```
Name = Axis10
Id = 101
A1 = 2887.9
A2 = 853.87   
A3 =2172.0
B1 =2956.9
B2 = 925.5250
B3 = 2181.8
C1 =2890.5
C2 =864.9
C3 =2072.6
```

Below is the final format of line I need in CSV file.(first and last line is just for reference to count the 8 characters.

```
$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678
Axis10  101             2887.9  853.87  2172.0  2956.9  925.52502181.8
+       2890.5  864.9   2072.6
$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678$2345678
```

Comment: Where are the commas in your CSV output?

Comment: And your sample list of variables is not in tcl code...

Comment: It looks more like you have an output format with fixed-width fields than CSV, in which case [`format`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm) will be useful.

Comment: yes the CSV file required to be feed into an application which will not recognize commas and will decides the variable values based on the fixed width fields

Comment: Then it's not a **C**omma **S**eperated **V**alues file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use tabs as your separator characters, or use fixed with field output.

### Tabs as Separators

If you're using [`csv::join`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-18/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.html#2) to make your line of output, just specify the optional *sepChar* argument as `\t`:

```
set line [csv::join $data "\t"]
```

### Fixed-width Output

In this case, you're not really producing CSV at all. The [`format`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm) command is *ideal* for this.

```
set data {Axis10 2887.9 853.87 2172.0}
set line [format "%8s%8s%8s%8s" {*}$data]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Donal's answer, here's a (probably over-engineered) way to go:

Assuming you have this already

```
set Name Axis10
set Id 101
set A1 2887.9
set A2 853.87   
set A3 2172.0
set B1 2956.9
set B2 925.5250
set B3 2181.8
set C1 2890.5
set C2 864.9
set C3 2072.6
```

Then

```
proc numberedFields {letter} {
    lmap n {1 2 3} {
        uplevel "set $letter$n"
    }
}
proc f {value} {format %-8s $value}
proc line {values} {join [lmap val $values {f $val}] ""}

puts [line [list $Name $Id "" {*}[numberedFields A] {*}[numberedFields B]]]
puts [line [list "+" {*}[numberedFields C]]]
```

Output

```
Axis10  101             2887.9  853.87  2172.0  2956.9  925.52502181.8
+       2890.5  864.9   2072.6
```